# CMake dynamically links `.a` files in `/usr/local/lib`

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to statically compile my program against another static library, for this example I'm using zeromq.  Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
add_executable( test test.cpp )
find_library(ZMQ NAMES libzmq.a)
message(STATUS ${ZMQ})
target_link_libraries( test ${ZMQ} )
```

It finds the `.a` file when I run `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..`

```
-- /usr/local/lib/libzmq.a
```

However, if I examine the `link.txt` file, the library is dynamically linked:

```
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o \
    -o test -rdynamic /usr/local/lib/libzmq.a
```

The weird bit is that if I move the file to a different directory, say `/usr/lib` and run `cmake ..` once more, it locates the new path to the library:

```
-- /usr/lib/libzmq.a
```

But now it has magically changed to static linking:

```
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o \
    -o test -rdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic -lzmq -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

The same thing applies to other libraries I'm linking to.

Why are all my libraries in `/usr/local/lib` being dynamically linked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use the path directly, and create an [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) instead, so you can explicitly declare it static:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
add_executable( test test.cpp )

find_library(zmq_location NAMES libzmq.a)
message(STATUS ${zmq_location})

add_library(zmq STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(zmq PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${zmq_location})

target_link_libraries( test zmq )
```

This may lead to a situation where the library *appears* to be linked dynamically, but the [cmake source code has the answer](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/797f7ad87d6f1b6dd7cbbb553d5525ac8ee390f1/Source/cmComputeLinkInformation.cxx#L970):

> If the target is not a static library make sure the link
>   type is shared.  This is because dynamic-mode linking can handle
>   both shared and static libraries but static-mode can handle only
>   static libraries.  If a previous user item changed the link type to
>   static we need to make sure it is back to shared.

Essentially, it's letting the linker handle detecting that the library is static if currently in dynamic-mode.

Comment: The path returned by find_library is definitely correct. I tried using your updated cmake file and now it is coming up as dynamic in *both* locations. I have also upgraded cmake to the latest version and still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my original question about the difference between `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib` is that, by default, `/usr/local/lib` is not one of the implicit link directories.  Therefore, a quick fix is to include this line in the config:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES /usr/local/lib ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})
```

However, as pointed out in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249421/cmake-dynamically-links-a-files-in-usr-local-lib/39250491#39250491), referencing files directly is not the way to go, instead one should use `add_library`.

Comment: You'll need to wrap the value of CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES in double quotes to ensure the whitespace between /usr/local/lib and the "old" value is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my DEMO:

```
find_library(VLQ_LIB NAMES vlq-shared PATHS /usr/local/lib/ REQUIRED)
find_path(VLQ_HEADER vlq.hpp /usr/local/include)
target_link_libraries(myproj PUBLIC VLQ_LIB)
target_include_directories(myproj PUBLIC VLQ_HEADER)
```

but during run, you still need to copy the shared lib to `/lib/` folder, for static lib, you can keep it under `/usr/lib`